# How do I directly access a PHP file located in my themes folder?

Tags: php

I have a file in my theme's folder called "test.php".

If I go to www.mysite.com/wp-content/themes/my-theme/folder/test.php the theme loads which I assume is a 404 error handled by WP. If I change the file name to be test.html I can access it no problem.

I tried adding the following code to my functions.php file (to add a rewrite rule):

```
add_rewrite_rule( 'test.php$', $relative_directory . '/folder/test.php [L]', 'top' );
```

but even having the htaccess rule didn't seem to do anything.

Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: You shouldn't be loading php files directly in the first place. What exactly does the file need to do? There's likely a better way to handle it.

Comment: I have a PHP file that I use to go get some data from my database to serve via ajax but right now going to that file does nothing but server a wordpress 404.

Comment: WordPress can get the data for you, and has built-in AJAX support. Using WP for data access gives you the added benefit of caching, sanitizing, escaping, and everything else you can use `$wpdb` for.

Comment: How do you contain your ajax calls to your theme folder? I don't understand why it has to be taken out of it when everything else can be defined internally.

Comment: You register your ajax calls in `functions.php` using a filter. Then you make the call to `admin-ajax.php` and WordPress passes it along. There's a plugin-based example [in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) but it works the exact same way for themes.

Comment: Sorry I was misreading the codex entry. The admin-ajax gets called when there's an ajax request.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you use the correct URL to access the file, everything is being handled in your web server level and WP doesn't run at all, so WP based solutions like changing rewrite rules will not help you.

It is most likely that there is some web server configuration that sends the 404 for any access to a php file at that folder (guess you should try if other php files there also return 404). You might be able to fix the web server configuration to match your needs, but as @EAMann commented, it is not the right way to write ajax for WP.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `RewriteRule`s in your .htaccess file? You should be able to access PHP files directly then. The first two lines with a `RewriteCond` make sure the rewrite to WordPress’ `index.php` does not happen if the file or directory exists.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /your-wp-site/index.php [L]
```

Comment: I wrote that line at the bottom of the .htaccess file and it broke the rest of the site. I can't say I really understand why, I'm a little perplexed :-/

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a custom WP template for that file to use display itself. Otherwise it is a stand alone file trying to be executed without permission or hooks.
 in this case you would need to add the file php code directly through WP and create a Page.

You can also open the "page.php" in your selected theme directory save it as "test.php" in that same directory and paste the entire content of your "test.php" PHP code inside the  division of your new "test.php" file.

Something like this:

```
<main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
<?php
//Your PHP Code Here!
?>
</main>
```

This just shows the basic  Division. You will need. If you need the entire other site content to display along with the test.php you will need to create a content-test.php file under the "templates-parts" directory in your theme.

Again, same thing except your gonna open "content-page.php" this time and save it as "content-test.php" under the "templates-parts" directory and past the test.php code inside the  where you would like this to show.

Back to the new "test.php" and replace the following line:

```
get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'page' );
```

with:

```
get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'test' );
```

The down side to this method is that when WP updates, it may or may not leave that file in tact vs. the first option which calls the php file as a post or page.

Hope that helps!